# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass -- again-- i dont get it. Constantly getting this error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController

def show
    @user = current_user
    @first_name = @user.first_name
    @last_name = @user.last_name
end

def settings
end

def pics
    @photos = current_user.photos.all
end


end
```

in the view of _pics.html.erb, I have

```
<% @photos.each do |p| %>
<%= image_tag p.image(:medium) %>
<% end %>
```

If I change it to current_user.photos.each do |p|, it works, which is weird. I don't get an error from this code on my other computer.

Comment: in which controller action are you in? are you sure that the pics method is ever called?

Comment: exactly, how do you get to rendering of _pics.html.erb? hitting the 'pics' action would render pics.html.erb, without the '_'

Comment: in the views for profile, I have a _pics.html.erb. I call the "@photos" in the _pics.html.erb. I'm new to rails. I figure since I have def pics with @photos declared under it in the profile controller, _pics.html.erb will automatically know what "@photos" is. Am I just understanding controllers and their views incorrectly?

Comment: I am rendering _pics as a partial in the show.html.erb inside a div,    <%= render 'pics' %>

Comment: what do you get when you do u=User.find(x); u.photos in a rails console

Comment: @timpone did u=User.find(1) and u.photos, console spit out all the images that belonged to that user

Comment: if you're rendering `show.html.erb`, you need to define `@photos` in the `show` action. Just rendering the `_pics` partial within show does not invoke the `pics` action in the controller.

Comment: @Shevaun when I do that, I get this error: "no block given (yield)" LocalJumpError in ProfileController#show, being the title of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you said, that you render the `pics` partial from your `show` view. Since the `show` view is rendered by the `show` action and the `show` action does not set the `@photos` variable, you can't use that variable. So to fix your problem, you'd need to set the variable in the `show` action.

You seem to think that rendering the `pics` partial will invoke the `pics` action, but that's not the case. An action will only be invoked if an URL is accessed that's mapped to that using the routing system. Rendering partials does not invoke any actions.

Also it should just be `@photos = current_user.photos` without the `all`.

Comment: edit, getting rid of the all method solved the problem. Thanks.